# Redirect one domain to another domain with popup

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, popup, http-status-code-301

I am using a 301 redirect from the old site to the new one, but those can be a bit jarring for users. So, I had a though. Can I get users to see a message if they are redirected from an older domain

**Example:** If user visit the old site, they get redirected to the new site and on the new site they get a popup explaining the old site is moved to this, Something like that.

Thanks in advance!